# How do I call intents from a web site

Tags: android, web, android-intent

I'm extremely new at Android development so please be patient.

I have an ASP.NET web site that will be accessed by an Android phone. On the site I want the user to be able to add a contact or an event to the calendar by clicking on a button. I take it I need to use intents. I saw in the documentation that I can make a phone call by using "tel" in the html, but do I do the same thing for calendar events and contact information?

If someone could point me to the proper documentation, or better yet, provide me with a simple sample, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Carlo.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.

- Set a link on your website with appropriate informations (perhaps include info in the URL e.g. http://mysite.com/telephone/67896988)
- In your manifest of the Android app, add intent filter so that your app opens that link:

  ```
  <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mysite.com" 
                  android:pathPattern=".*/telephone/.*" />
      </intent-filter>
  ```
- When use clicks on that link, Android will suggest the link to be opened by your app, in addition to browser. Your app then can look into the URL and do appropriate action.

Comment: I think to get the browser to initiate a call on the phone, you just need to include "tel:11235552345" as the URL for a hyperlink. But the thing is, I'm not writing an android app. This will be a web page that will be on a web server somewhere else.

Comment: You are right Carlo. I thought you had to do more processing than that so you had to receive it in your app.